# Convert classis asp if statement to php

Tags: php, asp-classic

Am still very new to PHP and need to convert existing pages to php, could anyone show me how to convert the code below to php please?

```
<%If rsMembership.Fields.Item("MemberOfGroup").Value = "0" then response.write ("Main Member")Else response.write ("Belongs to Member = ")&(rsMembership.Fields.Item("MemberOfGroup").Value)End if%>
```

Update: This works, not sure if its correct, cant seem to be able to put value as ="0", only works if I put <"1"

```
    <?php
if ($row_rsMembership['MemberOfGroup']< "1")
   {
   echo "Main Member";
   }
else
   {
   echo "Belongs to Member =" . $row_rsMembership['MemberOfGroup'];
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare a value in a PHP If statement use == and not =, i.e.:

```
if ($row_rsMembership['MemberOfGroup'] == "0")
   {
   echo "Main Member";
   }
else
   {
   echo "Belongs to Member =" . $row_rsMembership['MemberOfGroup'];
   }
```